# 3D printing extruder not warming up

Tags: diy-3d-printer, troubleshooting

I faced some problem with my 3D printer device. It seems the bed warms up without any problem, however, the hotend does not warm up!

Could you please help me identify what the problem is?

Comment: A photograph of the status panel would be helpful.

Comment: Are there `M104` or `M109` G-code commands found in the G-code file? Does the hotend warm up when you heat it up using the "prepare" menu item, e.g. for PLA? Furthermore, what kind of printer, hot-end are you referring to? Loose connection, broken heating element are the first to look at for a mechanical/electrical issue.

Answer (score 2):

I really hope the extruder doesn't warm up as this would be a problem with your stepper motor :)

I'm sure you mean the hotend doesn't heat up. This could be a number of things but i would start to double check the pinout in your code vs the pins on your mainboard and measure if it gives 12v/24v (depending on your PSU) output.

There's a lot more info required to properly help you.
What board are you using?
What OS are you using? Marlin or something else?
Share the relevant code of the OS for the hotend config/pinout
potentially share pictures of your wiring

Comment: This answer contains a lot of questions, this is not how SE works, this is not a forum, please save these for the comments under the question. When you have enough (50) reputation you will be able to post comments. Your questions are valid and the OP should add this to the question, however, they do not belong here.

Comment: How does that make sense? I can post answers but no comments before i have points, but to gain points one must answer questions. This is a really strange system and i don't appreciate being told what i say doesn't belong here. If that's how new members are treated I will find the way out very fast.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to make sure if your hotend is really not heating up. If you are saying the numbers are not showing (like when it is heating, the number on display or octoprint says 0/180) this could be a Thermistor problem. Check to make sure if your hot end is heating up by putting a paper or filament under it. DO NOT touch with your hand.

Second, If your hotend is truly not heating up, then several things can be happening.

1. Your hotend is wired wrong. Make sure your board is correctly wired.
2. Your hotend is dead. Change to different hotend and see if it works.
3. Your hotend is not getting enough power.